# Eight Queens 2-dimensional array with gotos errror

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on the Eight Queens problem with 2-dimensional array with gotos and when I try to run the code, it gives me a segmentation error and I can not seem to figure out why.
The eight queens puzzle is the problem of placing eight chess queens on an 8x8 chessboard so that no two queens threaten each other. Thus, a solution requires that no two queens share the same row, column, or diagonal.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;   

void print(int b[][8]);

int main()
{
    int b[8][8]={0},  
      r,
      c=0;
    b[0][0]=1; //putting 1st queen piece on the upper left corner

    /*column section*/
    next_col:
    ++c; //advance column position
    if(c==8) //if solutions for columns0-7 are found then print
        goto print;
    r = -1; //if not, start at the top of the column

    /*row section*/
    next_row:  
    ++r;
    if(r==8)
        goto backtrack;

    for(int i=0; i<c; ++i) 
        if(b[r][i] == 1)
            goto next_row;

    for(int i=1; (r-i)>=0 && (c-i)>=0; ++i)
        if(b[r-i][c-i]==1) //if conflict found in updiagonals
            goto next_row;

    for(int i=1; (r+i)<8 && (c-i)>=0; ++i)
        if(b[r+i][c-i] ==1) //if conflict found in down diagonal try next row
            goto next_row;
        else
            b[r][c]=1; //no conflicts found, so place queen & move to next col
    goto next_col;

    /*backtrack section*/
    backtrack:
    --c; //go back one column
    if(c== -1) // if past first column, all solutions found so terminate prog
        return 0;
     r = 0; //start looking from first row
     while(b[r][c]!=1) // while we haven't found the queen
         ++r; //move to next row of current column
     b[r][c]=0; //remove queen piece
     goto next_row;

     /*print section*/
     print:
     print(b); // print the board
     goto backtrack;
}   

void print(int b[][8])
{
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
            cout << b[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"2-dimensional array with gotos"_ Why? Trying every position _by hand_ would be easier!

Comment: I realize this, but it was our assignment

Comment: Good luck. I'm _really_ not going to read this. Can you afford not to do this assignment?

Comment: can you at least ident it properly? nobody is going to read this mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third for-loop, where you check the down-diagonals, there is an else that causes a queen to be placed if one of the diagonal squares is unoccupied, whereas you want it to be only placed if all of the diagonal squares are unoccupied. Remove the else, and it works fine (at least it does on my machine).